Azure Search scoring profile with dynamic boost
I'm trying to employ Azure Search into my ASP.NET Core app.
The problem I have is to how to create scoring profile with parameters which will hold the value of boost for certain fields. I know  it's feasible to create scoring profile with hardcoded boost value but not sure if that's feasible to create scoring profile with dynamic boost.
Found one example on how to specify it upon doing Search through SearchOptions :
// Define boosted fields in the search text
string searchText = "software engineer"; // The query text
string boostedFields = "title^3 description^2"; // Boost title by 3 and description by 2

// Define SearchOptions
var options = new SearchOptions
    {
        SearchFields = new[] { boostedFields }, // Specify boosted fields
        Size = 10, // Limit the number of results
        IncludeTotalCount = true
    };

// Execute the search
var response = await client.SearchAsync<SearchDocument>(searchText, options);

But it throws an exception saying that field title^3 not exist though it does! Seems like Azure Search does not parse ^3 as boosted value
Any ideas why it doesn't work?

your code is almost right, just need to swap the searchText and boostedFields. boostedFields is just a list of field names, and then you can boost value in the search condition referencing these fields based on your list..
var client = new SearchClient(new Uri(endpoint), indexName, new AzureKeyCredential(apiKey));

string searchText = "content:unpredictable^100 familiar"; // The query text
string boostedFields = "content"; 

SearchOptions options = new SearchOptions
{
    SearchFields = { boostedFields },
    Size = 5,
    IncludeTotalCount = true
};

SearchResults<SearchDocument> results = client.Search<SearchDocument>(searchText, options);
foreach (SearchResult<SearchDocument> result in results.GetResults())
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Score: {result.Score}, Document: {result.Document}");
}


So if let's say I want to look up Text1 my searchText variable has to be "content^100 Text1" ?

say the field name is: description, you want to boost text1 inside description during search.
string searchText = "description:text1^100"; string boostedFields = "description";

My case is that I have field1, field2 and searching by text1 with ability to boost values by field1, is that possible in this case?

From your example as I get it only searched by one column

you can add a list of columns: boostedFields = "col1, col2, col3", then use multiple of them in the search: searchText = "col1:text1^100 col2:text2^20 text3 . the key is that make sure the columns in the search query are also in the field list, otherwise you get the error.
